# What FOV do different phones give you with Google Cardboard?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm using Unity to make Google Cardboard VR apps. It seems to do a pretty good job of selecting the correct field of view for each phone I try.

I'm not trying to alter this, but I am interesting what the figures are for each device. I expect there's an equation based on screen size, or perhaps dot pitch and resolution, or maybe there's a table somewhere.